# Web server and listening nats at the same time

Tags: go

My code reads input from terminal and send those value to *nats* while it needs to have an http endpoint.

Separately it works but when I combine all of them it does not read from *nats*. If you could point me to a right direction I would appreciate.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    nats "github.com/nats-io/nats.go"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)


func main() {
    wd, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles(wd + "/template/main.html"))
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        data := TodoPageData{
            PageTitle: "Demo",          
        }
        tmpl.Execute(w, data)
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)

    type message struct {
        content string
    }
    var messages []message

    nc, err := nats.Connect(
        nats.DefaultURL,
    )

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer nc.Close()

    // Subscribe
    if _, err := nc.Subscribe("updates", func(m *nats.Msg) {
        fmt.Printf("Received a message: %s\n", string(m.Data))
    }); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // io r/w
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        if err := nc.Publish("updates", []byte(scanner.Text())); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        messages = append(messages, message{scanner.Text()})
        for _, message := range messages {
            fmt.Println(message.content)
        }
    }

    if scanner.Err() != nil {
        // handle error.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`http.ListenAndServe` is a blocking call.  Start it on a new goroutine:

`go http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil)`